# matplotlib pyplot.plot() marker colors

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

The code:

```
plt.plot(x,"g.")
plt.show()
```

generates:
[image]

When I try to specify colors in another way, lines are added:

```
plt.plot(x,"darkgreen",marker=".")
plt.show()
```

[image]

I don't need the lines. How can I use colors apart from the single character codes, without having the lines added to the plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `linestyle` to `"None"`:

```
plt.plot(x,color="darkgreen",marker=".", linestyle="None")
```